# Create column based on row value of another column.

Tags: python, arrays, calculated-columns

I'm sure this has been asked before, but I couldn't find exactly what I was looked for.

I have a np.array and I would like to create an additional column (C2) which has values dependent on another column (C1).

In pseudocode, I would like to make a column where (j = 2:n):

R1C1 = R1C2

IF |Rj-1C2 - RjC1| < 20  THEN  RjC2 = Rj-1C2

ElSE                           RjC2 = RjC1

I'm quite new to python, but I'm sure this is pretty straight forward.  I basically just need to know how I can insert this formula into python for an np.array.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty specific. Not sure there is a simple formula for this, because you are recursively generating the column rather than using existing data. You could do the following, where `a` is the index of your old column and `b` is the index of the column you want to fill in :

```
arr[0, b] = arr[0, a]
for j in range(1, n):
    arr[j, b] = arr[j - 1, b] if abs(arr[j - 1, b] - arr[j, a]) < 20 else arr[j, a]
```

Comment: This works very well.  I know this is a bit unrelated, but how can I label 'n' as the number of rows in my np.array?

Comment: `n, _ = arr.shape`

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to use zero index (i.e. row 0 being the first row, row 1 being the second row,  col 0 being first column, col 1 being second column, etc.) for ease of explaining and code implementation.

## The logic

Say we have a numpy array like this (call it array `a`) - as per your specification, both columns in first rows are the same.

```
a = np.array(
    [
        [10, 10],
        [15, None],
        [50, None]
    ]
)
```

- You want to set `n` as 3 (number of rows).
- The looping variant `j` takes the range of index `1` (inclusive) to `n` (exclusive). For our dummy example, `j` would be `1`, `2`. (i.e. 2 loops)

Note that Numpy indexing looks like this:

- `a[0][1]` means first row (row 0), second column (col 1).
- `a[1][1]` means second row (row 1), second column (col 1).

The condition being:

1. `if abs(a[j-1][1] - a[j][0]) < 20` ... then `a[j][1] = a[j-1][1]`
2. otherwise, `a[j][1] = a[j][0]`

i.e. Expected output:

```
[
    [10, 10],
    [15, 10],
    [50, 50]
]
```

## The code

This is a straight Numpy implementation

```
import numpy as np

# Create a sample numpy array as per specification
a = np.array(
    [
        [10, 10],
        [15, None],
        [50, None]
    ]
)

# get number of rows there are for looping upper bound
# for our dummy example, n = 3
n = a.shape[0]

# do the loop
for j in range(1, n):
    if abs(a[j-1][1] - a[j][0]) < 20:
        a[j][1] = a[j-1][1]
    else:
        a[j][1] = a[j][0]

# the array `a` is now is now updated to...    
# array([[10, 10],
#        [15, 10],
#        [50, 50]], dtype=object)
```

Also, I would suggest you to rename your question from the original:

**Create** column based on row value of another column.

to the new:

**Update** column based on row value of another column.

... since you always only have two columns (but can be many rows)